# URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource) - play back video from URL - MOOV atom - Elastic Transcoder

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming, html5-video, blob, m3u8

I am trying to play back a video (currently hosted on S3 with public access) by creating a blob URL.

I have used Elastic Transcoder to encode the video since it is supposed to set the MOOV atom to the top (beginning).

I am unable to get the code to work but also found a working example: [link here](http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/bufferAll.html)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video controls></video>
    <script>
      var video = document.querySelector('video');
      var assetURL = 'https://ovation-blob-url-test.s3.amazonaws.com/AdobeStock_116640093_Video_WM_NEW.mp4';
      // Need to be specific for Blink regarding codecs
      // ./mp4info frag_bunny.mp4 | grep Codec
      var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';
      if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
        var mediaSource = new MediaSource;
        //console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // closed
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
      } else {
        console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
      }
      function sourceOpen (_) {
        //console.log(this.readyState); // open
        var mediaSource = this;
        var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
        fetchAB(assetURL, function (buf) {
          sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function (_) {
            mediaSource.endOfStream();
            video.play();
            //console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // ended
          });
          sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buf);
        });
      };
      function fetchAB (url, cb) {
        console.log(url);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('get', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function () {
          cb(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.send();
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I looked at tools ie.e MP4Box or QT-FastStart but they seem to be kind of old school. I would also be willing to change from MP4 to M3U8 playlist but then I don't know what MIME types to use.

At the ned of the day I am trying to play back a video/stream and hide the URL (origin) potentially using blob.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first, even though this code seems to be taken from [mozilla documentation site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/readyState), there are a few issues - you are not checking the `readyState` before calling `endOfStream` thus the error you get is valid, secondly, the `play()` call is blocked by the [autoplay policy changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). If you add an error handler, you will actually see that the `appendBuffer` fails. Here is the updated snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video controls></video>
    <script>
      var video = document.querySelector('video');
      var assetURL = 'https://ovation-blob-url-test.s3.amazonaws.com/AdobeStock_116640093_Video_WM_NEW.mp4';
      // Need to be specific for Blink regarding codecs
      // ./mp4info frag_bunny.mp4 | grep Codec
      var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';
      if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
        var mediaSource = new MediaSource;
        //console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // closed
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
      } else {
        console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
      }
      function sourceOpen (_) {
        //console.log(this.readyState); // open
        var mediaSource = this;
        var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
        fetchAB(assetURL, function (buf) {
          sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function (_) {
            // console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // ended
            if (mediaSource.readyState === "open") {
                mediaSource.endOfStream();
                video.play();
            }
          });
          sourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
            console.log('an error encountered while trying to append buffer');
          });
          sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buf);
        });
      };
      function fetchAB (url, cb) {
        console.log(url);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('get', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function () {
          cb(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.send();
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So lets advance to next issue - the actual error. So, using `chrome://media-internals/` we can see that the video actually fails to load do to incompatibility with the ISOBMFF format:

[image: Chrome media internals error]

I am not familiar with Elastic Transcoder, but it seems that is it not producing an mp4 file suitable for live streaming. Also, if using mse, putting moov at the beginning is not enough, the video actually has to meet all of the [ISOBMFF requirements](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/190b670254ff/media-source/isobmff-byte-stream-format.html) - see chapters 3. and 4.

The working sample you mentioned is not a valid comparison since it uses the blob for the `src`, where the ISOBMFF rules do not apply. If it is fine for you to go that way, don't use MSE and put the blob directly in the `src`. If you need MSE, you have to mux it correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much! Maybe I am not fully understanding the code it might be completely over-engineered. You seem to know that stuff better than I do. Is there a simpler way to generate a blob URL and add it as a source to a webplayer or video element? Is there anything you can recommend. Your help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Well, why did you use MSE in the first place? You can simply do `<video src="https://ovation-blob-url-test.s3.amazonaws.com/AdobeStock_116640093_Video_WM_NEW.mp4" controls></video>` with your video. I am not sure I understand the requirements.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear. I was basically looking for an example to use a S3 URL, generate a blob URL and inject it as source into a video element. Similar to what you described in you last comment except that the src URL would be a blob URL. Hope I make sense :-). Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: I still can't put this together. Why do you need the src to be a blob url? This would make sense if you would be doing some kind of dynamic fetching, modifying the data, or am I missing something? Using the url in src is the best way for you, since your encoder cannot create a valid fragmented content.

Comment: You have a valid point. I think the idea is to hide the src URL of the video or stream or at a minimum make it more difficult to identify the source. It is an additional layer of security. I have seen this being in use by larger streaming and video on demand platforms. I did not come across any other best practices to hide/encode the URL. At the end I am trying to avoid having a plain URL (i.e. www.myserver.com/video.mp4) in the source code. Do you know of any other approach? Thank you!!

Comment: Well, again, as I said in the answer, if you want to use the blob URL you need a muxer that is capable of producing a video, that corresponds to ISOBMFF. As I said I haven't worked with the Elastic Transcoder and I do not know if it can be configured to produce such content, you may try wowza or set something up with ffmpeg.

Comment: I think I got it to work. Used ffmpeg to encode the MP4. Pretty sure the code as well as the ffmpeg command need some fine-tuning but it works. Thank you @Rudolfs Bundulis

Comment: @Meisold Yeah, ffmpeg is in most cases the best choice. How about an upvote or accept?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got the original code example to work by encoding my MP4 videos with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -c:a aac -movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof+frag_keyframe output.mp4 -hide_banner
```

Important is: `-movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof+frag_keyframe`

This setup also scales the video to 1920x1080 (disregarding any aspect ratio of the input video)

However, based on the comments of the original post, I do believe there might be a more efficient way to generate the blob url and ingest into a video tag. This example was copied straight from https://developer.mozilla.org. 
If anyone comes up with a better script (not over-engineered), please post it here. 
Thank you @Rudolfs Bundulis for all your help!

Comment: Unfortunately I have to take that back. Apparently it still does not work if videos have a certain size. The video I tested with was around 140MB. I just tried a 800MB file and the it would load forever, than eventually start playing...or the browser crashes. The documentation on https://developer.mozilla.org is very vague. There is also a comments made where you have to create a URL using  URL.createObjectURL() and assign it to HTMLMediaElement.src. I can't make any sense of the examples.